# Index Policy Update using Rest API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use the REST API model to update a collection to change its indexing policy [which the documentation says its possible]. FYI, i able to do GET, POST operations by properly hashcoding. Somehow the PUT operation on a collection does not seems to work. Below is my piece of code. It always comes back with response status not authorized. what am i missing the creating the hash

```
        ////Modify a collection
        verb = "PUT";
        resourceType = "colls";
        string col = "Collection1";
        resourceId = string.Format("dbs/{0}/colls/{1}", databaseId, col);
        resourceLink = string.Format("dbs/{0}/colls", databaseId);

        authHeader = GenerateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature(verb, resourceId, resourceType, masterKey, "master", "1.0");
```

The method GenerateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature mentioned above is just as per the following MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783368.aspx and it works fine for other GET\POST calls. Please let me know what am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed `resourceLink` is missing the collection id.

```
    resourceLink = string.Format("dbs/{0}/colls", databaseId);
```

Is it possible that the script is issuing a request to the wrong URI?

If not, can you post a full repro (including issuing the HTTP request) with endpoint + keys blanked out?